# Is a Range Cooker useful for vegan food?

Tags: cooking

My flatmate is vegan, and I don't really have any strong feelings that would compel me to insist on having animal products in the house, so I'm sort of tagging along.

I'm now building a new kitchen, and am trying to decide what kind of stove to put in. I've stumbled over "Range Cookers" that have three individual ovens with different shapes, as apparently that makes some difference when preparing meat.

I'm now trying to decide whether that would be useful to have or a waste of money. Are there recipes you could think of that are sensitive to oven shape, need several components baked at different temperatures or would profit from a special "browning-over" oven that is very flat?

[would mark this as a community wiki, but apparently I don't have enough reputation for that]

Answer (score 4):

Probably a waste of money. Maybe this is a matter of experience with a particular stove type, if you are used to it... Go for it. But some of the fancy accessories are specifically designed to cook and roast meat, some even have rotating skewers.

I would rather invest in a single oven with larger capacity. That comes in hand when baking breads or pizzas.